# count recursively with Parse.com database

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, parse-platform

I am trying to code a method which counts the number of user entries into the database. I know that this is going to be inefficient if run over a huge database so am restricting it to only the data from the last 24 hours. When I try to run it errors come up highlighting that there is an error in the network connect. What I am trying to do is cycle through all the usernames and count how many times they submitted to the database. The just list the data out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void display3km(ParseGeoPoint userLocation) {
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        listCombosNearBy.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
final Date yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query3 = ParseQuery.getQuery("FavFlavours");
        query3.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", yesterday);
        query3.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(final List<ParseObject> parseQuery, ParseException e) {
                final ParseUser[] allCombosArray = new ParseUser[parseQuery.size()];
                System.out.println(allCombosArray);
                for (ParseObject object : parseQuery) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < allCombosArray.length; i++) {
                        object.getParseUser("createdBy").fetchIfNeeded().getString("username");
                        allCombosArray[i] = object.getParseUser("createdBy");

                        query3.whereEqualTo("createdBy", allCombosArray[i]);

                query3.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
                    @Override

                    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                        final Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
                        if (e == null) {

                            results.add(allCombosArray + " " + count);
                        System.out.println(results);
                        }
                        arrayAdapter.addAll(results);
                    }

                });




                }
                }


            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the log cat code that gets sent to me.

```
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312): Process: com.lfg.fyp.taste_a_saurus, PID: 9312
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312): java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(ParseQuery.java:965)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(ParseQuery.java:959)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.parse.ParseQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseQuery.java:1571)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.lfg.fyp.taste_a_saurus.StatsUsers$1.done(StatsUsers.java:111)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.lfg.fyp.taste_a_saurus.StatsUsers$1.done(StatsUsers.java:1)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-25 22:36:26.777: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am writing for an android application in Java. I am using eclipse with the android jar import.

Comment: Note that Facebook closed support for Parse and it will eventually be faded out. They have open sourced their code.

Comment: Thank you, I only need it for a presentation next month

Comment: You are calling network operation on for loop which are causing this error. You also called for loop twice, remove foreach loop from your code.